# iOS 7 frame.origin.y changes back to original value upon orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

BACKGROUND:

I am writing a trivia APP for iOS7 using xCode 5.  As of right now there are two types of questions 1) Questions that require a text field input for the answer and 2) Multiple Choice Questions.  After the user enters/selects an answer they click the "Check Answer" button which displays a UIView which has an evaluation label (Correct/Incorrect) and a Reason label(which explains why their answer is correct or incorrect). Upon reviewing the evaluation the user can click the Next question button to display the next question.  I have to relocate the check answer button/Reason Box UIView/Next Question Button depending on the type of question that is displayed because the text field only takes up one line and the multiple choices are displayed in a tableview and thus takes up a lot more space.  The multiple choice questions and possible answers are contained within one UIView object while the text questions and text field are contained in a separate UIView (I toggle the hidden property to be true/false depending on which question is displayed).  I had to do this due to issues trying to get the original questions box to resize based on the height of the UITableView containing the multiple choice options.  This all works fine however...

MY ISSUE:
As stated above, I can move the necessary labels/buttons as needed by doing the following...

I can move the check answer button by doing the following:

```
//Moves Check Answer back to original position for text field questions
-(void)moveCheckAnswerBack {
    CGRect checkAnswerFrame = self.CheckAnswerButton.frame;
    checkAnswerFrame.origin.y = 126;
    self.CheckAnswerButton.frame = checkAnswerFrame;
}
//Moves Check answer button down for Multiple Choice Questions
-(void)moveCheckAnswerButton {
    CGRect checkAnswerFrame = self.CheckAnswerButton.frame;
    checkAnswerFrame.origin.y = 300;
    self.CheckAnswerButton.frame = checkAnswerFrame;
}
```

I move the UIView (which contains the Evaluation label and reason Label) and the next question button by doing the following:

```
 //MOVES REASONS UIView(containing evaluation label and reason label) and Next Button Back to original position for Text Questions
-(void)moveRBoxBack {
CGRect rBoxFrame = self.rBox.frame;
rBoxFrame.origin.y = 174;
self.rBox.frame = rBoxFrame;
self.rBox.hidden= false;
CGRect NBFrame = self.NextQuestionButton.frame;
NBFrame.origin.y = 313;
self.NextQuestionButton.frame = NBFrame;
}
//MOVES REASONS UIView(containing evaluation label and reason label) and Next Button Down for Multiple Choice Questions
-(void)moveRBox {
CGRect rBoxFrame = self.rBox.frame;
rBoxFrame.origin.y = 320;
self.rBox.frame = rBoxFrame;
self.rBox.hidden= false;
CGRect NBFrame = self.NextQuestionButton.frame;
NBFrame.origin.y = 463;
self.NextQuestionButton.frame = NBFrame;
}
```

Here's where the problem comes in... If I change the orientation of the device all of the above gets repositioned to its original position which causes it to overlap the multiple choice questions. (Note: this is not an issue for the text field questions due to the fact that the original positions are set up to work with the text field questions.)

I am attempting to solve this by placing a call to the appropriate methods within the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation as follows:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [self reOrderToPortrait];
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self reOrderToLandScape];
    }
}
-(void) reOrderToPortrait {
    NSString *qType = [_tempDictionary objectForKey:@"question_type"];
    //CHANGE LABEL WIDTH TO CONTRACT TO FIT ON PORTRAIT
    self.LabelWidth.constant = 240;
    self.mcQLabelWidth.constant = 240;
    // CHECK QUESTION TYPE 1 = TEXT 2 = MULTIPLE CHOICE
    if ([qType intValue] == 1) {
        [self moveCheckAnswerBack];
        [self moveRBoxBack];
    } else if ([qType intValue] == 2) {
        [self moveCheckAnswerButton];
        [self moveRBox];
    }

}

-(void)reOrderToLandScape {
NSString *qType = [_tempDictionary objectForKey:@"question_type"];
// CHECK FOR RETINA DISPLAY
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
    //CHECK QUESTION TYPE  1 = TEXT FIELD 2 = MULTIPLE CHOICE
    if ([qType intValue] == 1) {
        [self moveCheckAnswerBack];
        [self moveRBoxBack];
    } else if ([qType intValue] == 2) {
        [self moveCheckAnswerButton];
        [self moveRBox];
    }
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
        // iPhone retina-4.0 inch and change Label width 
        self.mcQLabelWidth.constant = 488;
        self.LabelWidth.constant = 488;
     } else{
        // iPhone retina-3.5 inch and change label width
        self.mcQLabelWidth.constant = 380;
        self.LabelWidth.constant = 380;
     }
  }
}
```

The positioning gets messed up whether I go from Landscape -> Portrait or from Portrait -> Landscape... It may also be worth noting that the elements remain in the proper location if I delete the willRotateToInerfaceOrientation method... however the content stops scaling to its proper width and remains at the default portrait width...

I am new to using Auto Layout so I am unsure if this is a constraint issue.  Also it may be worth noting that all of this is contained within a UIScrollview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Definitely an AutoLayout issue - try calling [myView updateConstraints]; in the rotation handler event?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @remus... to clarify I tried to call update constraints by putting it at the end of willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method (after it checks the orientation and changes the values... additionally i called it by doing [self.view updateConstraints]... If this was the correct place and way to call update constraints it unfortunately did not fix the problem :(... thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: Blat! I've found that often I have to fiddle and mess around a lot to get constraints to work properly.

Comment: @remus i've been fiddling and messing these constraints up all day every day for the last 3 days!  Auto Layout HATES me :(... thanks again for the suggestion though :D

Comment: That sounds like anyone who's ever worked with AL - me included :-/  Are you building in IB? You might try creating a duplicate storyboard, rotating it and getting the constraints right in landscape - then recreate those same constraints in your main SB and programmatically enable/disable them in the rotate handler?